# Method to allow email recipients to change their account information

Tags: soap, sugarcrm

I'm using SugarCRM Community Edition. I have a bunch of contact information. There are fields I have empty that would like filled. I want each user to be able to fill out a form and fill in those fields.

I'm not sure how to hook each contact into the database. I imagine creating a generic form that somehow hooks into the database using a key. The form/php is not the issue. What is the 'key' and where is the 'door'? I think the door is the SOAP API but I'm not sure. The key, maybe the tracker id?

The only thing I am familiar with as far as interaction between an email campaign and the contact is the campaign 'Tracker'. I know the tracker url with removeme is used for allowing the user to opt out of emails. Is there a way to use this tracker to allow the person to edit their information? I think the answer to this is easy but I need some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is using the built-in `REST api`.  There are a couple of helpful tutorials out there,  [here is a link to the one I  used for guidance](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-sugarcrmrest/index.html) in a similar situation.

You can have a form post the data to your sugar crm's `REST` gateway, accessible via the url `http://localhost/sugar/v2/rest.php`.

Although it is quite straightforward to implement, you may want to look at [this wrapper class](https://github.com/asakusuma/SugarCRM-REST-API-Wrapper-Class) that can be used to maybe keep things cleaner than the hacked up script churned out on the spur of the moment I used in my project.

Last but not least, be sure to glance over the documentation, in the [Web Services](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/docs/OS/6.3/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.3.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.3.0.html#9000434) section you will find more information.

Good-luck